# trying to calculate compute salary , compute deduction and compute net pay using abstract class in c#

Tags: c#

**abstract class**
Salary is calculated by multiplying the daily rate by the numbers of days worked in a month.
  im trying to calculate the salary which computes the salary of the employee and deduction which computes the deduction of the salary and net pay salary-deduction
for example: doctor=10000, teacher=20000, engineer=30000

trying to get the output
//

> ```
>        ID             001
>       Name            J
>       Salary          15750.00
>       Deduction       3386.25
>       Net Pay         12363.75
> ```

```
     namespace Practice
    {

////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////// class employee ///////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////// 

abstract class Employee
{
    int employeeid;
    string name;
    double salary, deduction, daysworked;
    public Employee()
    {

    }

    public int Employeeid
    {
        get { return employeeid; }
        set { employeeid = value; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public double Daysworked
    {
        get { return daysworked; }
        set { daysworked = value; }
    }

    public double Deduction
    {
        get { return deduction; }
        set { deduction = value; }
    }

    public double Salary
    {
        get { return salary; }
        set { salary = value; }
    }
    public virtual double calculatesalary()
    {
        return Salary * Daysworked;
    }
    public virtual double calulatededuction()
    {
        return calculatesalary() * Deduction;
    }
}


////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////// class sample1 ///////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////// 

class sample1 : Employee
{
    public sample1 (string name,int employeeid, double daysworked,double salary)
    {
        Name = name;
        Employeeid = employeeid;
        Daysworked = daysworked;
        Salary = salary;
    }
    public override double calculatesalary()
    {
        if (calculatesalary() <= 10000)
        {
            Deduction = 0.11;
        }
        if (calculatesalary() >= 10001 && calculatesalary() <= 20000)
        {
            Deduction = 0.22;
        }
        if (calculatesalary() >= 20001 && calculatesalary() <= 30000)
        {
            Deduction = 0.34;
        }
        if (calculatesalary() >= 30001)
        {
            Deduction = 0.58;
        }
        return calculatesalary() * Deduction;
    }

    }
}
```

my question is where did i get it wrong ? :/

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: where did i get it wrong ? is it my overried double calculatesalary ?any tips ?

Comment: It seems like `calculatesalary` calls itself recursively. You will probably get an infinite loop with this code. Perhaps you mean to call `base.calculatesalary`?

Comment: having an infinite loop error ,, im trying to have an if statement for salaries to have a deduction value, how should i do it ?

Comment: There are a few things wrong with this, why are you using an abstract class in the first place? Why are you calling a function inside of a getter? Why are you multiplying by something called deduction, when a deduction is normally something you subtract?

Comment: practice using abstract , while do all the process inside the class , and just basically call it in the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [John Wu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2791540/john-wu) pointed out, it ends up in an infinite loop since you invoke the `calculatesalary()` method in the `sample1` class recursively. Using `base.calculatesalary()` will invoke the base method and then perform additional logic in the derived class. Modify your your method as follows:

```
public override double calculatesalary()
    {
        var salary = base.calculatesalary();

        if (salary <= 10000)
        {
            Deduction = 0.11;
        }
        else if (salary >= 10001 && salary <= 20000)
        {
            Deduction = 0.22;
        }
        else if (salary >= 20001 && salary <= 30000)
        {
            Deduction = 0.34;
        }
        else if (salary >= 30001)
        {
            Deduction = 0.58;
        }

        return salary * Deduction;
    }
```

Please consider refactoring this class since it requires some fixes as [Dan Chase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3152516/dan-chase) mentioned.